# Remove CC Button from smfplayer in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I need to remove the CC button from a smfplayer on WP7. It dont have childrens or an buttons list. 
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to disable captions by specifying this attribute in XAML, it will hide the CC button.

```
            <Core:SMFPlayer CaptionsVisibility="Disabled">
```